# Mongoose React not filtering Users on age

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using React as front-end to display Filtered users on my website. Therefore I send a query to the backend (Mongoose) to filter users. But the problem is, Mongoose returns all the users instead of applying a filter.

```
export const getMembersGrid = (userId, token, seeking, minAge, maxAge, age) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/members?minAge=${minAge}&maxAge=${maxAge}`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Mongoose:

```
exports.members = async (req, res) => {
  let user = req.query.user ? req.query.user : 'asc';
  let sortBy = req.query.sortBy ? req.query.sortBy : '_id';
  let limit = req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit) : 6;
  try {
    let users = await User.find({
      $and: [
        { minAge: { $gte: req.query.minAge } },
        { maxAge: { $lte: req.query.maxAge } },
      ],
    })
      .sort([[sortBy, user]])
      .limit(limit);

    return res.json(users);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      error: 'users not found',
    });
  }
};
```

Sadly, I receive all the users and the filter is not working

Comment: This is the router request:
router.get('/members', members);

Comment: Can you post your `User` schema declaration?